# Live CD doesn't boot properly when trying to install

Tags: 11.10, installation

I'm to install ubuntu 11.10, but when I boot with ubuntu CD and go into "install ubuntu" or "try ubuntu" it just shows the background and doesn't do anything from there. Other people say that I should get a normal desktop with icons and taskbars, but well, mine doesn't show anything.

I can't even open the terminal, or any other hot keys. I've tried burning the CD 4 times, all different ways in different programs, and it still doesn't work. How can I install it?

Comment: Did you tried the check media option at the boot time. It will tell you whether all the bits are correct or not. Probably, last time I saw this issue with ubuntu 10.10 on a Sony VIAO laptop which has some different video chips. If your media is okay, then give us your machine h/w info.

Answer (score 1):

First, confirm the integrity of your iso and cd.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VerifyIsoHowto

Specifically, check the md5sum of the iso

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

Then, when you boot, hit the up arrows. You will get the old style boot menu:

[image: boot menu]

Choose "Install Ubuntu"

If that fails, you can try the alternate CD which has a more robust installer.

The concern I have , however, is that if the live CD does not work, then we probably need to debug your hardware, otherwise the install may fail in a similar way.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Litte weirder tho. I had Ubuntu running on a Dell PC. Then installed a wifi card which Ubuntu didn't recognize. Installed XP and found out that the PCI slot was faulty. Wanted to reinstall Ubuntu to see if it would recognize the card now. BUT I can't install it anymore. I got Ubuntu and Lubuntu 12.04. Md5sums are in order. Tried to install both via USB (have done this many times). OS wouldn't load. Neither install nor boot into RAM worked. Burnt Lubuntu to CD. Same result. I've never experienced something like this.